# Cannot Retrieve Full String with RequestParameter

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, cloudpage, cloudpagesurl

I have my AMPscript in CloudPage set as follow:

```
set @customer_ID = _subscriberkey
set @customer_Email = emailaddr
set @campid = RequestParameter("cid")
set @contactid = RequestParameter("conid")
set @procode = RequestParameter("pid")
set @cardnum = RequestParameter("cardnum")
set @refnum = RequestParameter("refnum")
set @cata = RequestParameter("cata")
set @catb = RequestParameter("catb")
set @catc = RequestParameter("catc")
set @catd = RequestParameter("catd")
set @cate = RequestParameter("cate")
```

with the AMPscript URL in my email campaign as follow:

```
%%=CloudPagesURL(123,'cid',CAMPAIGN_TRIGGER_CODE,'conid',CONTACT_ID,'cardnum',MERGE001,'refnum',MERGE008,'cata',MERGE003,'catb',MERGE004,'catc',MERGE005,'catd',MERGE006,'cate',MERGE007)=%%
```

Only the first word in my string is displayed, the characters after the spacing all truncated, e.g. `MERGE003` in my DE is `HELLO WORLD`, but only `HELLO` is displayed on my CloudPage.

Comment: based on your explanation, MERGE003 is actually a variable but I do not see how and where you are setting it. Please clarify all related information and we would able to help you, e.g. it would be better to see the actual content of `CloudPagesURL` and then a real example of what you are getting from it.

Comment: I have not been able to replicate your issue - I have successfully passed `HELLO WORLD` as a full string via `CloudPagesURL()` and collected and displayed via `RequestParameter()`. I think your issue may be with data or as @Niko mentioned, it might be an issue with the coding on your CP that is altering or otherwise manipulating your output.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in your CloudPage output as [@Niko](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/99298/niko) and [@Gortonington](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/12730/gortonington) have suggested.

It's worth mentioning that that are some subtle differences between the functions to pass values from an email to a CloudPage.

If I use the following link to test the methods for passing parameter values
-- where `test` and `triggeredDate` are columns in my sending data extension containing the values `whee!` and `7/8/2021 6:09:02 AM` respectively:

```
<a href="%%=redirectto(
              concat(
                  CloudPagesURL(1111,
                      'test1', test, 
                      'test2', AttributeValue('test')
                    ),'&test3=',test))=%%">cloudpagesurl</a>
```

And in my CloudPage:

```
test1 - naked personalization string
<br>AttributeValue: %%=AttributeValue("test1")=%%
<br>RequestParameter: %%=RequestParameter("test1")=%%
<br>QueryParameter: %%=QueryParameter("test1")=%%

<br><br>test2 - attributevalue
<br>AttributeValue: %%=AttributeValue("test2")=%%
<br>RequestParameter: %%=RequestParameter("test2")=%%
<br>QueryParameter: %%=QueryParameter("test2")=%%

<br><br>test3 - concat append
<br>AttributeValue: %%=AttributeValue("test3")=%%
<br>RequestParameter: %%=RequestParameter("test3")=%%
<br>QueryParameter: %%=QueryParameter("test3")=%%

<br><br>test4 - not explicitly passed
<br>AttributeValue: %%=AttributeValue("triggeredDate")=%%
<br>RequestParameter: %%=RequestParameter("triggeredDate")=%%
<br>QueryParameter: %%=QueryParameter("triggeredDate")=%%
```

I get this output when I click on the link from my inbox:

```
test1 - naked personalization string
AttributeValue:
RequestParameter: whee!
QueryParameter: whee!

test2 - attributevalue
AttributeValue: False
RequestParameter: whee!
QueryParameter: whee!

test3 - concat append
AttributeValue:
RequestParameter: whee!
QueryParameter: whee!

test4 - not explicitly passed
AttributeValue: 7/8/2021 6:09:02 AM
RequestParameter:
QueryParameter:
```

Observations:

- `test1`: AttributeValue is empty since I'm not referencing the sending DE column name, but the parameter name.  RequestParameter and QueryParameter have the same behavior.
- `test2`: AttributeValue is `False` since I'm not referencing the sending DE column name, but the parameter name is set with AttributeValue in the email.  RequestParameter and QueryParameter have the same behavior.
- `test3`: AttributeValue is empty since I'm not referencing the sending DE column name, but the parameter name.  RequestParameter and QueryParameter have the same behavior.
- `test4`: You don't actually explicitly pass parameters in the CloudPagesURL function if they're part of your send context.  They'll show up automatically and can be referenced using [AttributeValue](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue).

Key takeaway:

- Save some typing in your email, just retrieve the contextual values using  [AttributeValue](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue).

Reference:

- [AttributeValue](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue)
- [RequestParameter](https://ampscript.guide/requestparameter)
- [QueryParameter](https://ampscript.guide/queryparameter)
- [CloudPagesURL](https://ampscript.guide/cloudpagesurl)